# Is literal search still possible after stemming?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm a newbie to ElasticSearch and I can't seem to find the answer to this question.

Having added a `porter_stem` to my index analyzer, I can (obviously) no longer get literal term sequences using `match_phrase` like I used to. E.g. searching for **"playing my piano"** used to yield results that actually match the phrase precisely, but now they also include results like **"play my piano"** or **"plays my piano"** alongside it, with the more precise match not getting ascribed a higher relevance score.

My question is, is this just an inevitability that you can't have both stemming and literal search, or is there some solution to this I'm simply unaware of? Is either of the following possible:

1. perform literal searches where only **"playing my piano"** gets matched and nothing else
2. perform searches where **"playing my piano"** takes precedence over other, fuzzier results like **"play my piano"** or **"plays my piano"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question and yes it's possible to query and sort by `exact match`, `partial match`, and `fuzzy match` at the same time and sort by matching score.
I recommend you have multiple fields and different analyzers for your use case. Here is an example.

```
PUT test_multiple_analyzers
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "standard",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          },
          "porter_stem": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_porter_stem_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {<put your analyzer in here>}
    }
  }
}

GET test_multiple_analyzers/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "field_name.keyword": "plays my piano",
            "boost": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "plays my piano",
            "fields": [
              "field_name.porter_stem^3",
              "field_name"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
bool query : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html